# Android can't play some wav file with soundpool?

Tags: android, audio

Some .wav file I can't play with soundpool. I can't hear anything. Some files play just fine. Why?

code

```
    AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int streamVolume = mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    soundPool.play(soundPoolMap.get(sound), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the log file?

Comment: I did encountered some weird problem with .wav files in Android. My solution is to convert them in .mp3.

Comment: Are you using Samsung Galaxy S/Tab? As @xandy said, I found out you just can't play streaming WAV or OGG audio with those devices. I also converted them to Mp3.

Comment: i dont get any error, convert too mp3 solved the probleme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had lots of problems with soundpool and file formats. [Read my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850999/android-soundpool-problems), it might be helpful to you.

Basically, I changed to use MediaPlayer and had no more problems.

Comment: I got it working with Wav on HTC Sensation XE, Android 4.03. 

Specs are:

Codec: PCM S16 LE (araw) ///
Channels: 2 ///
Sampling Rate: 44.1kHz ///
16 bits per sample ///

Answer (score 1):

My finding using .WAV resource files with an *LG Optimus F3* running *Jellybean 4.1.2* is that its MediaPlayer library fails to decode:

1. Files whose bitrate exceeds 256kbps, and
2. Files whose duration is less than .075 seconds

The symptom in logcat in either case is:

```
V/SoundPool﹕ load: fd=49, offset=123932, length=536, priority=1
V/SoundPool﹕ create sampleID=3, fd=50, offset=536, length=123932
V/SoundPool﹕ doLoad: loading sample sampleID=3
V/SoundPool﹕ Start decode
V/MediaPlayer﹕ decode(50, 123932, 536)
V/SoundPool﹕ close(50)
E/SoundPool﹕ Unable to load sample: (null)
```

Rather than generate a fatal exception, the above error causes SoundPool to later attempt to use these "null" sounds, which in turn can cause the phone to lock up and/or lose frames.  ***Reducing the bitrate and using Audacity's "add silence" effect to lengthen the time of my sound files has solved this problem.***

In contrast to the symptom above, a successful SoundPool load looks like this in logcat:

```
V/SoundPool﹕ load: fd=55, offset=765700, length=3534, priority=1
V/SoundPool﹕ create sampleID=7, fd=56, offset=3534, length=765700
V/SoundPool﹕ doLoad: loading sample sampleID=7
V/SoundPool﹕ Start decode
V/MediaPlayer﹕ decode(56, 765700, 3534)
V/SoundPool﹕ close(56)
V/SoundPool﹕ pointer = 0x5f464000, size = 6976, sampleRate = 8000, numChannels = 2
```

If you are loading multiple sounds (which is the purpose of SoundPool), note your `sampleID` values as they tell which sound file failed to load, the first one loaded being `sampleID=1`, and so on.  That helped me distinguish "bad" from "good" .WAV files.

Note that I have ***not*** had this problem on several other platforms from LG and Samsung running Android Kitkat, which load higher bitrate and short sound files successfully.