# Android SoundPool problem on some devices

Tags: android, noise, soundpool, xiaomi, asus

I everyone, I'm trying to make a simple piano application, for each note I have a .wav file and I'm using soundpool class to make It play.

**BUT**

On a couple of Xiaomi devices and on Asus zenfone a kind of white noise is all I can hear and it's very annoying, also despite my effort I couldn't find any solution on the web, help me please!! ))

Here my declaring of aAttributes and soundPool objects in class scope:

```
private SoundPool soundPool;
private AudioAttributes aAttributes;
volumeNote = 1.0f;
volumeFeedBack = 0.6f;
```

here the code on onCreate method:

```
aAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                .build();
soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                .setMaxStreams(10)
                .setAudioAttributes(aAttributes)
                .build();
```

here an example of the code on the onClick method:

```
case R.id.btFaLow:
                    soundPool.play(faL,volumeNote,volumeNote,0,0,1);
                    break;
```

I hope these information can help to find the issue. Thank You all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some practical advises on the link below.

[Android can't play some wav file with soundpool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068068/android-cant-play-some-wav-file-with-soundpool/5071491)

Personally, I've used Soundpool with .mp3 files with no white noise issues.

After some searching, I've found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210921/set-audio-attributes-in-soundpool-builder-class-for-api-21) where CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION is used instead of CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC, which I believe may be more suited to what you're looking for.

> [CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioAttributes.html)
>
> Content type value to use when the content type is a sound used to
> accompany a user action, such as a beep or sound effect expressing a
> key click, or event, such as the type of a sound for a bonus being
> received in a game.

You can also checked out the code samples at coding in flow:
https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/soundpool
(I'm not associated with the site.)

Comment: Converting files from WAV to MP3 solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, experienced the same problem on a Xiaomi Redmi 6, and @Peppinhood's suggestion to use `.mp3` did the trick

For some reason, both `.m4a` and `.wav` produced heavily distorted sounds on that device.