# Android Game - SoundPool not playing sounds on Motorola Droid X2

Tags: android, game-engine, soundpool, motorola

I am working on a game that plays audio. The sounds play fine on my Samsung device and an HTC device. However, the sounds do not play on a Motorola Droid X2.

To initialize my SoundPool:

```
static SoundPool sp;
sp = new SoundPool(8, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
sp.load(context, resource_id, 1);
```

To play a sound:

```
sp.play(resource_id, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
```

I have tried searching for any bugs that may exist for Motorola devices and the SoundPool but have not found anything useful. Any and all help is appreciated.

I am loading five MP3 files, all less than 20kb each.

I create a skeleton project and included only the code below in the MainActivity, with the same results. Only loading one 12kb MP3 file, from the Resources class.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(16, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    int name = sp.load(this.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.brickhit,1);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            Log.d("mark","sleeping....");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    sp.play(name, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, -1, 1.0f);
```

Comment: How large are these audio files?  SoundPool is fine for a collection of small special effects, but if you start loading it with background music or voice acting, you'll quickly run out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation it turns out that Motorola Droid X2's will not play MP3 files through the SoundPool, at least not when loaded as above. I switched to .ogg format and the sounds are playing as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't experience the problem before, but maybe the stream count could be a problem like described here: [Android Soundpool problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850999/android-soundpool-problems)